# Two regex expressions needed

Tags: regex

Hi I am trying to match (ignore the carats as I am using those to show whitespace)...

```
'- go'
'. go'
'go -'
'go a'
'go &'
```

but not

```
' go'
'go'
'go '
```

Basically I need one expression to match any character before the word 'go' or 'GO' or 'Go' except for a whitespace.

And I need a second expression to match any character AFTER the word 'go' or 'GO' or 'Go' except for a whitespace.

Can someone help please?

Comment: Which regex tool/language are you using?

Comment: I am using the Regex search feature in MS SQL Management Studio.

Comment: Try this regex: `(^|\S)go(\S|$)`

Comment: @anubhava how about `(^|\S+)\s*go\s*(\S+|$)`?

Comment: I believe OP doesn't want any space before/after `go`

Comment: @anubhava Didn't OP said that he wrote the '' to make the spaces visible? And my regex will also fit if there aren't spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS (and Visual Studio) use a slightly different regex syntax. Well, slightly...

The first one would be:

```
([^:b]+):b*[gG][oO]
```

and the second one would be

```
[gG][oO]:b*([^:b]+)
```

Unfortunately, "0 or 1" is not supported, so there's no other way than the asterisk (0 or more). The parentheses create a capturing group for the characters you're after. `:b` is MS speak for a space.